# Set view width as the latger view of group

Tags: android, xml, view

I have 3 views in vertical LineartLayout. 
I want to make width of each the same, but as small as the larger view can be.

Each view is a button, and have different text size. So if i set wrap_content, every button have different size. If i set fill_parent - every view is as large as screen.

So how can i do that without runtime code (only xml layout markup)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set all button's widths to `fill_parent` with the `layout_weight="1"` for each of them. Like

```
<Linearlayout ...>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ........ 
    anddroid:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ........ 
    anddroid:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ........ 
    anddroid:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Setting weights
2. Set the absolute dimensions for the layout width and height of the view
   Eg:
           android:layout_width="30dip"
           android:layout_height="15dip"
3. Set the style attributes for the buttons:
   A Button can have a few style attributes that can be set on it:

   1. normal button – no style attributes required, this is the default
   2. normal right style – style=”?android:attr/buttonStyleRight”
   3. small style – style=”?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall”
   4. small right style – style=”?android:attr/buttonStyleSmallRight”

Any of the above three things can be done to achieve the desired result.